# AgularFire Combine 2 streams

Tags: firebase, rxjs, angularfire2

I'm trying to combine 2 streams of data coming from Firebase using AngularFire but I'm having a hard time.

I have a collection called `incomeShops` that has a reference for the `userID` that created that specific record. What I need to do is to make a second call to fetch the user's data but I can't.

Any help?

Here is what I have:

```
getAllIncomeShops() {
    const shops = this.venueService.getIncomeShops()
        .snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(
            switchMap(incomeShopSnaps => {
                // Mapping the result to extract the data I need using snapshotchanges().
                return incomeShopSnaps.map(incomeShopSnap => {
                    const shopObject = {
                        id: incomeShopSnap.payload.doc.id,
                        ...incomeShopSnap.payload.doc.data()
                    };
                    // On the shopObject there is a property called suggestedBy which contains a STRING with the user's ID.
                    // Trying to fetch the user's data to insert on the shopObject.
                    this.userService.getUser(shopObject.suggestedBy).valueChanges()
                });
            })
        ).subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
}
```

Comment: So for each `incomeShopSnaps` you want to make a separate request?

Comment: Hey @martin yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an array of observables and wait until all of them complete with `forkJoin()`.

```
switchMap(incomeShopSnaps => {
  // Mapping the result to extract the data I need using snapshotchanges().
  const requests = incomeShopSnaps.map(incomeShopSnap => {
    const shopObject = {
      id: incomeShopSnap.payload.doc.id,
      ...incomeShopSnap.payload.doc.data()
    };
    // On the shopObject there is a property called suggestedBy which contains a STRING with the user's ID.
    // Trying to fetch the user's data to insert on the shopObject.
    return this.userService.getUser(shopObject.suggestedBy).valueChanges()
  });

  return forkJoin(requests); // You can eventually `map()` results into something...
}),
```

Comment: thank you, but in this case, where would I map the results? I just tried the code but it didn't console anything :(

Comment: `forkJoin` requires all source observables to emits at least once and complete. So are you sure all `.valueChanges()` complete? Maybe you'll need to chain each of them with `take(1)`

Comment: Hey Martin, sorry this is still not clear. `The valueChanges()` will return an `Observable` that should be ok right? Is there a way to check if it's completing? In that case, should the `take(1)` be after the `switchmap`?

Comment: `take(1)` goes after every `valueChanges` so `valueChanges().pipe(take(1))`. You can see if they complete by using `tap({ complete: () => { ... })`.

Comment: Hey @martin I did that! I guess it completes because I can log the result for the `getUser` but it feels like it's ignoring the first request, because I don't get anything for it. I tried to adding the `tap()` right after the switch map as well and nothing. Any suggestion on that? Thanks bud

Comment: I just tried a few other things and still no go :( Here is the gist for it: https://gist.github.com/iconio/668ef50513254a7aa6f0f4f17a06080d also, I'm getting this error: 
>core.js:5873 ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

Comment: You're missing `return` inside `incomeShopSnaps.map()`.

Comment: I can't believe that was it! :D thank you soooo much!